# Multiple local servers on same ip without port numbers in the url

Tags: linux, networking, routing, domain, synology

I want to run multiple servers on 1 single ip, that can be accessed by its requested domain.

Example:

Server 1: A Synology nas, runs on local ip 192.168.178.100
Server 2: A ESXI server, runs on local ip 192.168.178.200

Both servers go out on the same ip. As example 84.24.82.97

When you go to `myExampleDomainName.com` you will end up on my Synology nas
And when you go to `anotherExampleDomainName.com` you will end up on the ESXI server.

And also when you go to `server1.example.com` you will end up on server 1 and the same for server 2.

If the solution means I need to add a virtual machine to the ESXI server, then thats possible.

Comment: Is this browser based access only, e.g. the web interface of your vcenter? If it is, you will need to use 443 only. A decent solution might a a reverse proxy in a DMZ that is reachable via your public IP and then uses SNI to deliver the correct site, using the domain to determine it. [Here is how this would be done via nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni). Please let me know if this goes in the correct direction and I will provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @PatrickR. Yes it's for browser based access only, I want to host multiple servers under 1 ip. Like 3 synology nasses and idk some other webservers. I have tried some nginx stuff but it didnt work out because i didn't understand that well what to do. Just want to redirect the request to the requested local server

Comment: In this case, this is indeed a duplicate of the question Tim_Steward just linked. If you need further help, you'll need to point out what exactly you've tried and where you're getting lost.

Additionally, I might be a bit heretical here, but if you indeed do not understand the basic principles of webservers and reverse proxying, maybe you shouldn't expose these services to the internet.

Comment: @Patrick R, agreed. there is certainly a chance of exposing your servers to the wild here if you mess up the config.